# Подскажите, что не так?

Tags: python

Есть задание: Рассматривается множество целых чисел, принадлежащих числовому отрезку [3912; 9193], которые удовлетворяют следующим условиям:
− сумма цифр числа кратна 9;
− шестнадцатеричная запись числа не заканчивается на 21.
Найдите количество таких чисел и максимальное из них.
Правильный ответ: 585 9189. Скажите, пожалуйста, что не так с кодом?

```
s = 0
c = 0
for i in range(3912, 9193+1):
    n1 = i
    if (i // 16) % 16 != 21:
        s = 0
        while i != 0:
            s = s + i % 10
            i = i // 10
        if s % 9 == 0:
            c = c + 1
            n = n1
print(c, n)
587 9189
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(i // 16) % 16
```

замените на

```
i % 256
```

и `21` в шестнадцатеричной системе это `33`

```
s = 0
c = 0
for i in range(3912, 9193+1):
    n1 = i
    if i % 256 != 33:
        s = 0
        while i != 0:
            s = s + i % 10
            i = i // 10
        if s % 9 == 0:
            c = c + 1
            n = n1
print(c, n)
```

также можно уменьшить код если идти с шагом `9`

```
c = 0
for i in range(3912+3, 9193+1, 9):
    if i % 256 != 33:
        c += 1
        n = i
print(c, n)
```

Comment: хорошая идея про шаг 9! может вечер, но навскидку сразу не сказал бы почему между этими двумя числами нет чисел с суммой цифр кратной 9 :)

Comment: @Zhihar признак деления на 9 такой же, как и на 3, только вместо 3 там 9 :)

Comment: @Эникейщик, ну да, я же говорю, что вечером тупил :)

Answer (score 1):

ну можно решить в лоб:

```
count = 0
found = 0

for i in range(3912, 9193 + 1):
    # определить сумму цифр
    digits = 0

    value = i
    while value != 0:
        digits += value % 10
        value //= 10

    # определить на что заканчивается число в 16ричной записи
    last = i % 256

    # выбрать нужные числа
    if digits % 9 == 0 and last != 33:
        count += 1
        found = i

print(count, found)
```

если ввести функцию, то можно упростить код, но он все таки не рассчитан на случаи, когда надо найти миллиарды чисел, в этом случае лучше первый вариант:

```
def digits(value):
    res = 0
    while value != 0:
        res += value % 10
        value //= 10
    return res


data = [i for i in range(3912, 9193 + 1) if i % 256 != 33 and digits(i) % 9 == 0]

print(len(data), data[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

можете попробовать так:

```
for i in range (3912,9194):
 if sum([int(k) for k in str(i)])%9 == 0 and i%256 == 33:
     print(i)
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что нужно решить без использования строк, только циклы и условия